# How to open a web page when geoserver is ready

Tags: batch-file, geoserver

I have Geoserver startup.bat file that looks like this:

```
@echo off
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Startup Script for GeoServer
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

cls
echo Welcome to GeoServer!
echo.
set error=0

rem JAVA_HOME not defined
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto noJava

rem JAVA_HOME defined incorrectly
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto badJava

echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.

rem GEOSERVER_HOME not defined
if "%GEOSERVER_HOME%" == "" goto noHome

rem GEOSERVER_HOME defined incorrectly
if not exist "%GEOSERVER_HOME%\bin\startup.bat" goto badHome

goto checkDataDir

:noJava
  echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined.
goto JavaFail

:badJava
  echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
goto JavaFail

:JavaFail
  echo This environment variable is needed to run this program.
  echo.
  echo Set this environment variable via the following command:
  echo    set JAVA_HOME=[path to Java]
  echo Example:
  echo    set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk6
  echo.
  set error=1
goto end


:noHome
  if exist ..\start.jar goto noHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined.
goto HomeFail

:badHome
  if exist ..\start.jar goto badHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
goto HomeFail

:HomeFail
  echo This environment variable is needed to run this program.
  echo.
  echo Set this environment variable via the following command:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_HOME=[path to GeoServer]
  echo Example:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_HOME=C:\Program Files\GeoServer
  echo.
  set error=1
goto end


:noHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined.
goto setHome

:badHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
goto setHome

:setHome
  echo Temporarily setting GEOSERVER_HOME to the following directory:
  cd ..
  set GEOSERVER_HOME=%CD%
  echo %GEOSERVER_HOME%
  echo.
goto checkDataDir


:checkDataDir
  rem GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR not defined
  if "%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" == "" goto noDataDir
  goto run

:noDataDir
  rem if GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR is not defined then use GEOSERVER_HOME/data_dir/
  if exist "%GEOSERVER_HOME%\data_dir" goto setDataDir
  echo No valid GeoServer data directory could be located.
  echo Please set the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR environment variable.
  echo.
  echo Set this environment variable via the following command:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=[path to data_dir]
  echo Example:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=C:\Program Files\GeoServer\data_dir
  echo.
  set error=1
goto end

:setDataDir
  set GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=%GEOSERVER_HOME%\data_dir
  echo The GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR environment variable is not defined correctly.
  echo Temporarily setting GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR to the following directory:
  echo %GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%
  echo.
goto run


:run
  set RUN_JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
  cd %GEOSERVER_HOME%
  echo Please wait while loading GeoServer...
  echo.
  "%RUN_JAVA%" -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar
  cd bin
goto end


:end
  if %error% == 1 echo Startup of GeoServer was unsuccessful. 
  echo.
  pause
```

I need to open a web page once Geoserver is up and running. I'm not familiar with batch scripting and all my attemps have failed so far. I know I need to call start "www" "web page adress" but have no idea where in the code I should put this piece.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but maybe this is what your looking for?

```
:run
  set RUN_JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
  cd %GEOSERVER_HOME%
  echo Please wait while loading GeoServer...
  echo.
  start /wait "%RUN_JAVA%" -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar
  start www.website.com
  cd bin
goto end
```

That will start the Java file and wait for it to finish, then launch the webpage, presumably the server will be ready if it gets to that point, so when the jar has finished executing the website will appear.

Comment: When run Windows say the -D cannot be found. To clarify what I am trying to do: When you start Geoserver with the file I posted above, it loads all the map layers, starts the engine and gets accessible at http://localhost:8080/geoserver. Geoserver is also able to server web pages which you can access at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www.
I want the bat file to open http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www once it is ready to use, but I don't know how.